# Why sigmoid curves appear in quantitative analysis of many biological phenomena?

Tags: biochemistry, mathematical-models

I know two examples:

1-The binding of hemoglobin to oxygen (binding of oxygen to one site of hemoglobin induces conformational changes which increase the affinity of the other sites for oxygen - the curve could be interpreted as transition from a low affinity T sate to a high affinity R state). The plot can be seen [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Hemocyanin#/media/File:Hb_saturation_curve.png/)

2-The denaturation of DNA by temperature (when one segment of the double helix opens, base stacking is disrupted, making the denaturation of the rest of the molecule easier); Another [plot](http://www.lpt.ups-tlse.fr/local/cache-vignettes/L570xH327/fig_web-1647a.jpg)

The two examples I gave were actually of positive cooperative phenomena, that is, the occurence of a first event favours the next events. There is also the titration curve, which is a sigmoid, but I don't think it's correlated.
I'm asking that because I found it amazing that the same sort of curve appeared in the study of such different subjects.
**Are these examples somehow correlated, that is, for which sort of phenomena sigmoid curves are expected?**

Comment: Logistic functions have a sigmoidal curve. Logistic functions are used extensively in ecological models. This question as it stands appears too broad. You can come up with lot of examples. You should narrow it down to a specific issue.

Comment: Agreed. These curves are widespread in population genetics as well.

Comment: Tons of examples in psychophysics and neuroscience...

Comment: Agreed - psychometric curves in a host of tests follow sigmoids.

Comment: can you rephrase question so that it is not encyclopedic but rather about biological principles? so far seems you can answer it extensively searching pubmed on [sigmoidal curve](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=sigmoidal+curve)

Comment: Dinosaur Growth Rates, neuron sensitivity to angle (auditory system) etc...

Comment: voted down for too broad scope

Comment: @aandreev I have reformulated.

Comment: seems more interesting now. can we remove hold?

Comment: I've already edited the question. Could you reconsider if it's still too broad or at least suggest other editions?

Comment: why is this question closed? i also want to know the answer/opinion. glad that there's still one person answered this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following: take any one-dimensional process that is described by gaussian function. If you integrate such process along variable, you will get a sigmoidal curve. For details see [normal and cumulative distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Now, the question is: how many biological processes are described/modeled by Gaussian distribution and dependencies? A lot!

Let's take a look at dinosaur growth from [Revisiting the Estimation of Dinosaur Growth Rates](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3864909/)

[image: Dinosaur growth rate]

This figure describes how size of dinosaur changes with some time (model, I assume). Remember link between gaussian and sigmoidal functions? If you differentiate, that is find how fast aforementioned sigmoidal function changes, you will get gaussian bell-curve! Which tells you: dinosaur grows faster during middle age, and slower before and after that.

DNA denaturation curve is sigmoidal because efficiency of denaturation is again gaussian. At low temperatures very limited amount of molecules will denature, but at high temperature there are no more molecules to denaturate left, so the bell-curve. Anothe explanation goes like that: at low temperature additional heat doesn't change much because it is still too "cold", at higher temperature same amount of heat is just a drop in a bucket, barely noticeable.

Comment: How do you say that relationship of temperature and denaturation should be gaussian? Gaussian CDF looks sigmoidal; that doesn't mean that all sigmoidal curves have a gaussian explanation.